# NSInvalidArgumentException *** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, console, google-vr

i'm trying to develop a project with Xamarin Forms, specially Ios shared code where, after i binded the Google Vr SDK library perfect with ApDefinition & StructAndEnums classes and the GVRSDK static library, i ve some problem to solve.
When i insert the GVRVideoView widget into my ViewController, two buttons about Fullscreen and Cardboard View Mode doesn't appear; i've insert their own enable methods into code to do that.
Also when i tap them the app crashes and the debug console give me these exception. I don't know what i should try to do.
Maybe anyone can help and discuss with me these problem?

```
2017-04-12 12:45:00.413 App18.iOS[1335:1127396] INFO 
[vr/gvr/capi/src/gvr.cc:109] Initialized GVR version 1.30.0
2017-04-12 12:45:04.872 App18.iOS[1335:1127349] Xamarin.iOS: Received 
unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSInvalidArgumentException *** -[NSURL 
initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter
2017-04-12 12:45:05.179 App18.iOS[1335:1127349] Objective-C exception 
thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: *** -[NSURL 
initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x1b773b55 <redacted> + 152
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x1a9fb067 objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x1b773a85 <redacted> + 0
3   Foundation                          0x1c01fc69 <redacted> + 120
4   Foundation                          0x1c01fbdb <redacted> + 42
5   App18.iOS                           0x00098e67 -[GVRTransitionView 
loadView] + 510
6   App18.iOS                           0x00098c0f -[GVRTransitionView 
initWithFrame:delegate:] + 190
7   App18.iOS                           0x0008e277 -
[GVROverlayViewController init] + 246
8   App18.iOS                           0x000a0f6d -[GVRWidgetView 
goIntoFullscreenMode] + 76
9   App18.iOS                           0x000a198d -[GVRWidgetView 
didTapFullscreenButton:] + 20
1
0  UIKit                               0x209d6805 <redacted> + 76
11  UIKit                               0x209d6799 <redacted> + 62
12  UIKit                               0x209c0dc9 <redacted> + 478
13  UIKit                               0x209d60d5 <redacted> + 604
14  UIKit                               0x209d5c1f <redacted> + 2094
15  UIKit                               0x209d0b5f <redacted> + 2798
16  UIKit                               0x209a2703 <redacted> + 308
17  UIKit                               0x21135d37 <redacted> + 2254
18  UIKit                               0x211306db <redacted> + 4186
19  UIKit                               0x21130abd <redacted> + 144
20  CoreFoundation                      0x1b72ffdd <redacted> + 12
21  CoreFoundation                      0x1b72fb05 <redacted> + 424
22  CoreFoundation                      0x1b72df51 <redacted> + 1160
23  CoreFoundation                      0x1b6810ef CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 
470
24  CoreFoundation                      0x1b680
f11 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
25  GraphicsServices                    0x1ce2bb41 GSEventRunModal + 80
26  UIKit                               0x20a05e83 UIApplicationMain + 150
27  App18.iOS                           0x00fd2d6c
```

wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___int
     ptr_intptr + 324
    28  App18.iOS                           0x00f764b0 
    UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 52
    29  App18.iOS                           0x00f76470 
    UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 204
    30  App18.iOS                           0x0042d820 
    App18_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 192
    31  App18.iOS                           0x00690ae4

wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 256
    32  App18.iOS                           0x0036cd45 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 
    1528
    33  App18.iOS                           0x003b9937 do_runtime_invoke + 78
    34  App18.iOS                           0x003bb90d do_exec_main_checked + 84
    35  App18.iOS
                        0x0035b0ad mono_jit_exec + 194
    36  App18.iOS                           0x0042c660 xamarin_main + 2484
    37  App18.iOS                           0x01143be1 main + 112
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x1ae6e4eb  + 2

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you are passing 'nil' as the parameter in the method [NSURL 
initFileURLWithPath:].
Add a breakpoint to check the value you are passing in the method.
Also share the code so we can advise you better.